# Rendering checkboxes from DB and then update the DB if modifyed

Tags: php, html, mysql, checkbox

Thanks for coming!
So on the DB I have Table1 and Table 2, they have the same columns.
What I want to do is that an administrator check the changes requested on Table2 and with a checkbox for each column decide which ones are ok and which others aren't.

So far I have this [image: How it looks]

If there are changes between Original and Modified tables the cell turns its color to green and Autochecks itself...
So far so good, but.

If I press the Submit button I don't seem to catch the VALUE of the ticked checkbox, so far the maximum I accomplished to catch was a "ARRAY" value, literally, not the content but "ARRAY" just like that, the code of each cell is way to long, Right now I'm focusing on getting the first row right so i can implement that to the other ones, so here is what it looks like: (sorry for the awful mess it is)

```
<tr>
          <td style="text-align: center">Codigo de Cliente</td>
          <td style="text-align: center"><?php echo $row1['idClientes']; ?></td>
          <td <?php if($row1['idClientes']===$row2['idClientes'])echo "bgcolor='green'  ";?> style="text-align: right"><?php echo $row2['idClientes']; ?><input type="checkbox"  name="checkbox[]" id="checkbox" value:"<?php echo $row2['idClientes']; ?>" <?php if($row1['idClientes']===$row2['idClientes'])echo "checked='checked' onclick='this.checked=!this.checked;' value:'".$row2['idClientes']."'";?> ></td>

 </tr>
```

And here is the PHP

```
    <?php if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    $idClientes =$_POST['checkbox'];

  echo "<script>
alert('$idClientes'),
</script> ";}
```

That echo/alert gives me 'Array' as a result when it should be '14359.

Any advice? Thanks in advance!
PD: If the solution excludes Jquery/Javascript that would be awesome, Im not familiar with those languages yet, so only php/mysql/html for now.

Comment: It's because your input name is arrayed so the resulting post will be in an array. You have loop through the array or implode it

Comment: I forgot to mention that, every single checkbox haves a different name, So I don't know if this still applies. , if so can you elaborate a little bit how to implode it if theres no separators? Thanks for answering! @Rasclatt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by the comment(s), your form inputs have array names:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="14359" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="2222222" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="dvdza@whatever.com" />
```

If a couple are checked, will produce an array like this:

```
Array
    (
        [checkbox] => Array
            (
                [0] => 14359
                [1] => dvdza@whatever.com
            )
    )
```

If you want to retain the array names but be specific about labeling, you need to make the array associative:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[idClientes]" value="14359" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[idSomethingElse]" value="2222222" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[email]" value="dvdza@whatever.com" />
```

When checked would give you:

```
Array
    (
        [checkbox] => Array
            (
                [idClientes] => 14359
                [email] => dvdza@whatever.com
            )
    )
```

This way you can then do:

```
if(isset($_POST['checkbox']['idClientes']))
    $idClientes = $_POST['checkbox']['idClientes'];
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the Array you're getting back should contain all the values that are checked. It should actually help you complete the rest of the implementation of getting the values of the ticked checkboxes, by just indexing an element that you need or by looping through the array.

Comment: I forgot to mention that, every single checkbox haves a different name, So I don't know if this still applies. Thanks for answering!